# Converting SharePoint List Form to a PowerApp

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online, powerapps

I'm looking for input on the best approach to converting a SharePoint list form to a PowerApp.  The list currently has the following field type:

- 15 text fields
- 5 choice fields
- 5 multi-select choice fields
- 3 multi-line text fields (not rich text)

There are 20,000+ items in the list, with 1k+ new items added every month.

When creating the PowerApp, should each choice field be converted to a new list? I'm wanting to make the fields as dynamic as possible and avoid hard coded values.

I'm not opposed to moving all of the list items to a CDS entity if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use PowerApps to customize the SharePoint list form. There is a command in the command bar of a modern list to do that

[image]

If you don't want to use Choice fields, you can use simple text fields and in PowerApps connect to SharePoint lists as the source of the dropdown options. Then you can let the end users maintain the values for the dropdowns easily.

With this approach, the SharePoint list maintains all other functionality, i.e. you can use list views and embed list view web parts in SharePoint pages. A customized form will not work on a mobile device, though.

You can also build a stand-alone PowerApp that stores items in the SharePoint list. This is independent of the SharePoint list form customization. Such an app could be used on a mobile device, but there are limitations around the number of list items that the app can pull from the SharePoint server at any one time. It may not be suitable for big lists.

PowerApps is easy to learn and there are lots of resources just a web search away.

Comment: i've created some simple forms but this one failed to port over due to the number of choice fields. are lookup columns the issue or choice fields?

Does PowerApps handle the locking of items if two users try to work the same item at the same time?

User A starts editing items 1123    
User B wants to make a quick update to 1123

Comment: Please don't tack on more questions, especially not in a comment. Ten choice fields should not break PowerApps. It does have limits, but they are a lot higher than that. What do you mean with "port over"? Are you importing something from somewhere else? Start with the SharePoint list and click the Customize Forms command, then build the form there. You  cannot "port" into PowerApps.